# iteration of a JSON containg objects

Tags: javascript, html, function, object, methods

I am trying to write a function that takes pokemon’s name as an argument and find out which all pokemon have that name in their “next_evolution” field

Consider the following JSON dataset -
visit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json

now for that, I've written the following function:

```
var infoOfPokemon = function(nameOfPokemon,allPokemon){
for(x in allPokemon){
if(allPokemon[x].next_evolution.includes(nameOfPokemon)){
  console.log('pokemons found: '+allPokemon[x].name)
} else{
  null
}
 }
}
var nameOfPokemon =prompt('enter the name of Pokemon')
infoOfPokemon(nameOfPokemon,pokemonData.pokemon)
```

but it is returning an error which says
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' nextEvolution.js:4090 of undefined

Comment: `.includes` is an `array` function.

Comment: You're using a `for...in` loop, so try using just `x` instead of `allPokemon[x]`, as the `for...in` loop takes care of that for you.

Comment: @Feathercrown that's not correct.  `allPokemon` is an array (according to the linked json file) and `for ... in` iterates over the indices of the array, not the values.  Hence `allPokemon[x]` is correct.  `for ... of` would work with this, but support is not top-notch yet.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx My apologies, I confused the two.

Comment: even if I write just[x] instead of allPokemon[x] it returns the same error.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx next_evolution is an array of objects, what should I do so that my function reads the value of that object.

Comment: Ideally, you should include a pared-down version of the data you point to off-site.  StackOverflow is trying to build a great collection of questions and answers, but to do so, the relevant data should be included here, in a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 2):

One or more of your pokemon does not have a 'next_evolution' field set (for example, the one with id 3 in your file).  Hence `allPokemon[x].next_evolution` evaluates to undefined and you cannot read 'includes' on that.

Check for the existence of `next_evolution`, first.

```
if (allPokemon[x].next_evolution && 
    allPokemon[x].next_evolution.includes(nameOfPokemon)) { ...
```

Comment: though your code is running but  it's not returning any value.the console block appears empty

Comment: @SmAshhar this is only intended to solve your problem with your undefined.  I was hoping you would solve your other problems yourself :)  But as a hint: `next_evolution` is an array of objects, `nameOfPokemon` is a string.  `includes` will not work here.

Comment: hey am an absolute beginner to coding and I am unable to find a way out here. please help me out.

Comment: @SmAshhar well sure.  But keep in mind this is a QA site, and it should be used as such.  you'll essentially want to check if any of the entries in next_evolution has the name 'nameOfPokemon'.  So first filter the entries, and then check if the length of the resulting list is higher than 0. More or less like so: `(allPokemon[x].next_evolution || []).filter(function(p){ return p.name === nameOfPokemon}).length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

> and find out which all pokemon have that name in their “next_evolution” field

That should make you think of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). You want to filter the list of pokemon to find the matching ones.

But, as already pointed out, you need to be able to return `false` in your filter predicate if the pokemon you're testing does not have a `next_evolution` field.  You can do that via testing, as suggested in another answer: `pokemon.next_evolution && pokemon.next_evolution.includes...`, or you can default it, as below:  `(pokemon.next_evolution || []).includes...`

(Note though that both you original and that answer miss a step, which is to then collect that `name` properties from those `next_evolution` values.

So here is a simple function which should filter the list to find the correct items.  To use it with a call to your API, I wrap it in a `fetch` call, and simply `console.log` the results.  Obviously, you might well have other ways to call it.

```js
const infoOfPokemon = (name, all) => all.filter(pokemon => 
  (pokemon.next_evolution || []).map(p => p.name).includes(name)
)

fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(allPokemon => console.log(
    infoOfPokemon('Butterfree', allPokemon.pokemon) //~> [{Caterpie}, {Metpod}]
  ))
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts but evena after making the following changes in the code

if (allPokemon[x].next_evolution && 
allPokemon[x].next_evolution.(obj)=> obj.name).includes(nameOfPokemon)) { ...

though code is executing but its not returning any value.
the console section appears blank.

Comment: That's interesting, as it's running correctly in my browser.  With a node-based `fetch` API, it's also working at https://runkit.com/crosseye/so-50215870.  Note that with Promise-based code, there will be a bit of a delay.  It should return a Promise, which will be resolved with the data from that API.  If you already have that data in a variable, then you don't need the `fetch` wrapper, or anything but the call to the main function.  That should return.

Comment: The only reason that I used `fetch` here in the first place was that the API data is too long for these snippets, and I thought it was your job, not mine to reduce it to a manageable subset!

Comment: Note that you can't comfortably make those changes to my code, as I use an arrow function with a single expression body, which means you can only include sub-expressions, and not statements such as `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **includes** function directly on array having objects instead of single object. It will give false as output.
For e.g:

```
var pets = [{'name':'cat'},{'name':'dog'},{'name':'bat'}];

console.log(pets.includes("cat"))  //false
```

This results in **false** always.
Proper way is to use a map to get a particular object field on which you want to use includes function.

e.g:

```
var pets = [{'name':'cat'},{'name':'dog'},{'name':'bat'}];

console.log(pets.map((obj)=> obj.name).includes("cat")); //true
```

In Your case first see if allPokemon[x].next_evolution is undefined or not (i.e **next_evolution** key is present or not) 
code becomes:

```
if (allPokemon[x].next_evolution && 
allPokemon[x].next_evolution.(obj)=> obj.name).includes(nameOfPokemon)) { ...
```